# BeautifulSoup web scraping for a webpage where information is obtained after clicking a button

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I am trying to get "Amenities and  More" portion of the Yelp page for a few restaurants. The issue is that I can get to the Amenities from the restaurant's yelp page that are displayed first. It however has "n more" button that when clicked gives more amenities. Using BeautifulSoup and selenium with the webpage url and using BeautifulSoup with requests gives exact same results and I am stuck as to how to open the whole Amenities before grabbing them in my code. Two pictures below show what happens before and after click of the button.
[image]

[image]

1. "Before clicking '5 More Attributes': The first pic shows 4 "div" within which lies "span" that I can get to using any of the above methods.
2. "After clicking '5 More Attributes':  The second pic shows 9 "div" within which lies "span" that I am trying to get to.

Here is the code using selenium/beautifulsoup

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL ='https://www.yelp.com/biz/ziggis-coffee-longmont'

driver = 
 webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Fariha\AppData\Local\Programs\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
yelp_page_source_page1 = driver.page_source



soup = BeautifulSoup(yelp_page_source_page1,'html.parser')
spans = soup.find_all('span')
```

Result: There are 990 elements in "spans". I am only showing what is relevant for my question:

[image]

Comment: Note: don't name your variable as `all`. That would override the built-in function called [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#all) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to extract the data directly from the JSON api on the site. This could be done without the overhead of selenium as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/ziggis-coffee-longmont')
#r = session.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/menchies-frozen-yogurt-lafayette')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

# Locate the business ID to use (from JSON inside one of the script entries)
for script in soup.find_all('script', attrs={"type" : "application/json"}):
    json_text = script.text.strip('<!->')
    
    if "businessId" in json_text:
        gaConfig = json.loads(json_text)

        try:
            biz_id = gaConfig["legacyProps"]["bizDetailsProps"]["bizDetailsMetaProps"]["businessId"]
            break
        except KeyError:
            pass

# Build a suitable JSON request for the required information
json_post = [
    {
        "operationName": "GetBusinessAttributes",
        "variables": {
            "BizEncId": biz_id
        },
        "extensions": {
            "documentId": "35e0950cee1029aa00eef5180adb55af33a0217c64f379d778083eb4d1c805e7"
        }
    },
    {
        "operationName": "GetBizPageProperties",
        "variables": {
            "BizEncId": biz_id
        },
        "extensions": {
            "documentId": "f06d155f02e55e7aadb01d6469e34d4bad301f14b6e0eba92a31e635694ebc21"
        }
    },
]

r = session.post('https://www.yelp.com/gql/batch', json=json_post)
j = r.json()

business = j[0]['data']['business']
print(business['name'], '\n')

for property in j[1]['data']['business']['organizedProperties'][0]['properties']:
    print(f'{"Yes" if property["isActive"] else "No":5} {property["displayText"]}')
```

This would give you the following entries:

```
Ziggi's Coffee 

Yes   Offers Delivery
Yes   Offers Takeout
Yes   Accepts Credit Cards
Yes   Private Lot Parking
Yes   Bike Parking
Yes   Drive-Thru
No    No Outdoor Seating
No    No Wi-Fi
```

Reviews could be obtained as follows:

```py
r_reviews = session.get(f'https://www.yelp.com/biz/{biz_id}/review_feed', params={"start" : "0", "sort_by" : "relevance_desc", "q" : ""})
reviews = r_reviews.json()

for review in reviews["reviews"]:
    print(review["user"]["markupDisplayName"])
    print(review["comment"]["text"])
    print("----------")
```

Giving something like:

```
Jennifer C.
I am a huge local fan of Ziggi&#39;s. I find every experience with them them to be good.  I love that they have an app so you can order ahead if you happen to be closer to Main St vs Hover.  The app is easy to use and lets me customize everything. <br><br>I love that they have two drive thru locations and they are easy to navigate to and from. Their staff is always so nice too. <br><br>Their rewards program has been great for me since I go often enough to get the free drinks. <br><br>And the drinks!!  From coffee to lattes to italian sodas!! The frozen chocolate peanut butter drink!! The Colorado Sunrise and Limesicle!! Their citrus green tea! I mean really?? Its all so good. <br><br>Another favorite of mine is their large kids drink menu. Its so nice to take my son for a treat there. <br><br>I am so glad they are part of Longmont and  definitely have indefinite plans to remain a permanent customer.
----------
Judd O.
My wife was sold a defective gift-card as a gift for a colleague&#39;s wedding, it didn&#39;t work when the new bride attempted to use it at an Estes Park Ziggi&#39;s.  Funnily enough, the recipient&#39;s mother had said the same thing happened with a GC she&#39;d bought from this same location.  We brought it back here and were told that, without the receipt that was the size of a thimble, we were boned.<br><br>That being said, we did get our second card&#39;s free drink and it&#39;ll be our last.<br><br>We&#39;re just lucky we only spent 25 bucks.<br><br>Edit: Also, the manager&#39;s name is Pristine, there&#39;s some grand irony in that.
----------
```

**How was this solved?**

Your best friend here is your browser's network dev tools. With this you can watch the requests made to obtain the information. The normal process flow is the initial HTML page is downloaded, this runs the javascript and requests more data to further fill the page.

The trick is to first locate where the data you want is (often returned as JSON), then determine what you need to recreate the parameters needed to make the request for it.

To further understand this code, use `print()`. Print everything, it will show you how each part builds on the next part. It is how the script was written, one bit at a time.

Approaches using Selenium allow the javascript to work, but most times this is not needed as it is just making requests and formatting the data for display.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Very much appreciated. Now, since I am very new to python and web scrapping, could you recommend any resource that I can read or watch to understand the code. It works fine, but I want to understand it too. For example, I know what 'find_all' does but what does  "attrs={"type" : "application/json"}" doing. How did you come up with json_post's documentID? etc.

Comment: I've updated the explanation to help. The `attrs` part allows you to match only tags containing the specified attributes. If you look at the source HTML you will see `<script>` tags with various parameters, this helps to focus on just the entries containing the JSON.

Comment: Late bump on the question around coming up with json_post's documentId. I'm specifically looking for `"operationName": "GetReviewSummary"`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the review summary, but reviews can be obtained via a separate GET. I have updated the answer to show how

Comment: Thanks! I've used this before, though it requires going to each rating instead of obtaining the results in one call. `GetReviewSummary` has a graphql query (much like `GetBusinessAttributes` above), so I was curious how theose `documentId` values were obtained. It seems to be a sha256 hex value, but the components aren't straightforward.

new s.ApolloLink(((e,t)=>(e.extensions.documentId=function(e){const t=(0,Se.S0)(rt(e));return Oe()("sha256").update(t).digest("hex")}

Comment: The `documentId` values I seem to remember can be seen in the post requests seen in a browser's network tool for the page