# How do I build a suitable JSON request to post it to an API?

Tags: html, web-scraping, python-requests, yelp, network-traffic

I am trying to scrape the "Amenities and More" portion of the Yelp, and came across this very helpful answer that explains the best way to do it ([BeautifulSoup web scraping for a webpage where information is obtained after clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838411/beautifulsoup-web-scraping-for-a-webpage-where-information-is-obtained-after-cli)).

The problem is, I am unsure how the person who posted the answer (Martin Evans) knew that typing "GetBusinessAttributes" and "GetBizPageProperties" would tell Yelp to return the requested data. I used my network dev tools to check what data was being requested when I visited https://www.yelp.com/biz/ziggis-coffee-longmont, but found no mention of "GetBusinessAttributes" or "GetBizPageProperties".

Can someone explain how he knew that sending "GetBusinessAttributes" and "GetBizPageProperties" would return the desired data?

Comment: I don't think this is something that could be easily explained in a single answer.  However, I can point you to Yelp's API documentation which may provide some of what you're looking for: [Yelp Fusion API - Making Requests](https://www.yelp.com/developers/graphql/guides/requests)

Comment: I read the API documentation prior to asking this question. Martin's method does not use Yelp Fusion's API endpoint, which is under [link](https://api.yelp.com/v3). His method also does not follow documented Yelp GraphQL way of scraping data as I looked at the network traffic and the payload is not in JSON.

When I analyzed the network traffic when loading a business's Yelp page, I found that "operationName":"GetBusinessHealthScoreAlert" was requested, but no mention whatsoever of "GetBusinessAttributes" or "GetBizPageProperties". This is quite perplexing to me.

Comment: Using Firefox's network dev tool I found no references to "GetBusinessAttributes." Using Chrome's network dev tool I found a reference by pressing "Ctrl + F" while in the network tab and then searching for that text.  It shows up in what looks like a generated Javascript file and it looks like a method definition `GetBusinessAttributes($encBizId: String) { ... }`  So, like his answer in that linked question suggests, it looks like Martin reverse engineered the process little by little to obtain what he needed.  That can be a very time consuming process, which is why I suggested the API.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me! The API is an option, but the problem with it is that they limit you to 5,000 calls per day, unless you ask for more. This is somewhat problematic for the project I have in mind.