# How/where to to find documentId to build suitable JSON request for Yelp?

Tags: json, web-scraping, post, postman

In this answer to this question [BeautifulSoup web scraping for a webpage where information is obtained after clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838411/beautifulsoup-web-scraping-for-a-webpage-where-information-is-obtained-after-cli), Martin's JSON request includes documentIds for each operation (GetBusinessAttributes and GetBizPageProperties). Where does he find these documentIds?

I understand that I need examine the network traffic as @Martin suggested. I spent hours examining the network traffic when visiting https://www.yelp.com/biz/ziggis-coffee-longmont, and I am able to find some documentIds (e.g. the documentId for GetBusinessHealthScoreAlert is "9757b0dd458b4ad4a5922f28cbd77a1d284093c6b0e84a13c95f01c56f776e9d"). However I am unable to locate the documentIds for GetBusinessAttributes or GetBizPageProperties. I am not sure if I am missing something or doing something wrong.

Comment: Please clarify - Title of question and content seems to ask different things. Answer of @Martin is well written, he picked the information, pointed at in your last sentence, from script tag in source code. Would be great if you could focus a bit more, thanks

Comment: Martin’s code demonstrates how to find the biz_id, build the payload, and post it to Yelp’s API, but within the payload, the documentIds are seemingly pulled out of thin air. @Martin just lists them. I want to learn how and where he found these documentIds. I already analyzed each component of the network traffic searching for the documentIds for GetBusinessAttributes and GetBizPageProperties, but I can’t seem to find it.

Comment: @Ian did you ever find an answer for this? I'm try something similar: see https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31516

Comment: @alpacafondue No, sorry. I was never able to figure this out.